# Stop to pass the click event to annotation (prevent from popup)

Tags: google-maps, titanium, apple-maps

I am using ti.Map

I want to do something when user click annotation.

```
//make mapview
    var mapView = Map.createView({
        mapType:Map.NORMAL_TYPE,
    });

//make anotation
    annot= Map.createAnnotation({
            latitude: myLatitude
            longitude: myLongitude
            title: myTitle
            width:'100dp',
            height:'100dp'
    });

// add annotation
    mapView.addAnnotation(annot);

//handle the annotation click 
    mapView.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        if (evt.clicksource == "pin"){ // if user click annotation
            //do something
            return; //I try this 
        }
    });
```

it works well.

However, after do something, annotation popup appears (as default behavior)

I want to stop the annotation popup.

1)I try to prevent event passed to annotation class.

or

2)Stop annotation not to react the click event.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the annotation popup just try to comment the property `title` of `annot`. I tried this and its working fine.

```
//make anotation
annot= Map.createAnnotation({
        latitude: 19.151201,
        longitude: 72.938237,
        // title: 'myTitle',
        width:'100dp',
        height:'100dp'
});

//handle the annotation click 
mapView.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.clicksource == "pin"){ // if user click annotation
        //do something
        alert('Pin clicked');
        return; //I try this 
    }
});
```

And just the alert is visible no annotation popup.

Some updated code :

```
annot= Map.createAnnotation({
    latitude: 19.151201,
    longitude: 72.938237,
    title: ' ',
    backgroundColor : 'transparent'
});
// add annotation
mapView.addAnnotation(annot);

//handle the annotation click 
mapView.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
if (evt.clicksource == "pin"){ // if user click annotation
    alert('Pin clicked');
    evt.annotation.title = "";
    // return; //I try this 
}else if (evt.clicksource == "map"){
    alert('map');
    evt.annotation.title = " ";
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I commented out the title, so popup doesn't come out , however somehow 'click' event for mapView is not fired....

Comment: @whitebear which SDK are you using?

Comment: 5.1.1GA and ti map 2.4.1(iOS)